# JButton Image Icon not displaying .png file

Tags: java, swing, png, embedded-resource, imageicon

I've been looking everywhere for a solution to this and  read some similar posts related to this problem but none of them worked for me.

I'm trying to display the image **"b.png"** on the JButton and when i roll over the button the icon changes.

```
package GUI_JButton;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Gui extends JFrame {

    private JButton reg;
    private JButton custom;

    public Gui() {
        super("Title goes here");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        reg = new JButton("reg button"); // create reg button
        add(reg); // add reg button to JFrame

        // initialize images
        Icon b = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/imageA.png"));
        Icon x = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/imageB.png"));

        custom = new JButton("custom button", b); // create custom button
        custom.setRolloverIcon(x);
        add(custom); // add button to JFrame

        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        reg.addActionListener(handler);
        custom.addActionListener(handler);

    }

    private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    String.format("%s", event.getActionCommand()));

        }

    }

}
```

The images are in a folder named images which is in the src folder alongside the `Gui.java` file and the `TESTMain.java` file.

The error i'm getting is a null pointer exception from Main. I have tried

```
Icon b = new ImageIcon("images/imageA.png");
```

This compiles but the image is not displayed. I have also tried

```
custom = new JButton("custom", new ImageIcon("images/imageA.png"));
```

And

```
custom = new JButton("custom", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/imageA.png"));
```

I know that `getClass().getResource()` is prefferred as the images need to be compiled with the jar.

Any ideas on getting my images to display?

Comment: Change `getResource("images/imageA.png")` to `getResource("/images/imageA.png")`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your images folder needs to be in the same folder as your compiled `.class` files, instead of in `src` with your `.java` files.