# ImageIO wont import BufferedImage correctly

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

Error thrown--

Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)

Code--

```
try {
        playerImage = ImageIO.read(Player.class
                .getResourceAsStream("/toon.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

File path--

H:\workspace\Isaac\resources\toon.png

Ive researched this a bit but none of the solutions have really worked for me. any ideas?

Comment: The toon.png file doesn't appear to be within the jar file boundaries, and if so, cannot be obtained as a resource.

Comment: should resources be in the src file??

Comment: They should be off of the class files, the bin directory. If you're using Eclipse and you create a directory off of src, then I believe that you will also be creating an equivalent directory in bin and your images will be accessable.

Comment: My 3 main package folders and the "resource" folder are all in the bin folder for my java project

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? And I don't see a bin or src directory in the file path that you posted. Please clarify.

Comment: when i make a resource folder in eclipse, it doesnt put the resource folder in the bin folder.

Comment: @Noah No the resource folder does not go to the bin folder only its content (including the packages) and assuming it is a source folder in your project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null! when using ImageIO.read to load image as bufferedImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424834/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-input-null-when-using-imageio-read-to-lo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Isaac` is your project folder, then the way your are reading should work. Please check whether the directory `resources` is a source folder (in eclipse it should have an icon of a folder with an overlay of a java package), if not then right click on it and got to `Build path` and choose `Use as Source Folder`.

Your directory structure should look something like this:

before compiling

```
H:\workspace\Isaac
├───resources
│       toon.png
│
└───src
        Player.java
```

after compiling

```
H:\workspace\Isaac
├───bin
│       Player.class
│       toon.png
│
├───resources
│       toon.png
│
└───src
        Player.java
```

`getResourceAsStream` looks for the image in `bin` and not in the one in `resources`

Comment: @Noah please open a cmd and execute `tree /F H:\workspace\Isaac` and post the directory structure in your question. we need to know the content of each directory.

Comment: I fixed it by making a new project in eclipse and adding all the contents of the isaac project to the new one.  Not sure what was going on but thanks for helping me

Comment: Im new to this website, how do i reward people for helping me out??

Comment: @Noah If you find an answer helpful you may upvote it by ticking the *up* arrow at its left. If an answer could help you best to solve your problem then you may mark it as accepted by ticking the *checked* icon at it left too. Please take a time for a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for basic functions of this site, there will be a reward for you as well in form of a badge ;-)