# Java - Loading a image from resource location with ImageIO

Tags: java, resources, classloader, javax.imageio

I have been trying to load an image from my "Resources" folder in my project for the past couple of hours, the task would seem to be simple yet I have been pulling my hair out about it.

My current code:

```
private Image bg_img;
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
bg_img = ImageIO.read(classLoader.getResource("imgo.jpg"));
```

Yet I keep getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at com.conquest.gui.MainPanel.<init>(MainPanel.java:80)
at com.conquest.gui.RenderFrame.createControls(RenderFrame.java:40)
at com.conquest.gui.RenderFrame.createFrame(RenderFrame.java:35)
at com.conquest.gui.RenderFrame.<init>(RenderFrame.java:23)
at com.conquest.main.Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

I have tried multiple things (and suggestions from other questions asked here) but to no avail.

I have also tried adding trailing and beginning slashes which didn't work.

I have tried some suggested code to see if my Resource location is setup properly, which seemed to work:

```
private String getFile(String fileName) {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");

        //Get file from resources folder
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                result.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            scanner.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result.toString();

      }


      public MainPanel(){
            System.out.println(getFile("test.txt"));        
      }
```

Which does output every line of the file, yet I still cannot grab my image...

---

[image]

Comment: Where are your images located with regard to your class files?

Comment: The class i am using to load the image is in: com.conquest.gui.MainPanel
and My image is in Resource in root.

Comment: @Dyachynull Is the image in the same directory as `test.txt`?

Comment: Please upload an image of your file/image configuration to an image sharing site, and then post a link to the **image** (not to the web page) so that we can insert it into your question.

Comment: What @HovercraftFullOfEels said. If Windows, take a screenshot of the folder in Windows explorer. If Mac, take a screen of the folder in Finder. If Linux, do an `ls` of the directory and just paste it here.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels http://i.stack.imgur.com/1Gmxh.png is my project.

Comment: Thanks. Images have been added to your question, something that you can do in the future when you gain more reputation points. I wonder if your resource folder needs to be inside the src folder (actually in the bin folder, but it will appear to be in both).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks alot, http://i.imgur.com/TVVlmIc.png is my project now, i am still getting the same error though. I did notice a test.txt in my /bin folder so i thought i would try to put the images in there too, the error is gone, but when i try to draw the image, it "breaks" my PaintComponent without throwing an error(White screen) http://i.imgur.com/CoCVLg0.png


EDIT:
It seems that this code:

ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
bg_img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("imgo.jpg"));

Doesnt allow my paintcomponent to draw without error :/

Comment: Also, its now throwing the same error as before, randomly :/

Comment: [have a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32083560/522444)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ImageIO wont import BufferedImage correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215235/imageio-wont-import-bufferedimage-correctly)