# GUI close issue?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a program which displays two buttons and changes the image of one of the buttons on roll over. I am getting an error on my

```
press.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

part, And it looks like this: The method setDefaultCloseOperation(int) is undefined for the type ButtonClass. Even with the exit on close commented out there are more errors, please help.

Main class (with error):

```
package Buttons;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main_buttons{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ButtonClass press = new ButtonClass();
    press.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    press.setSize(300,200);
    press.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

ButtonClass class:

```
package Buttons;

import java.awt.FlowLayout; //layout proper
import java.awt.event.ActionListener; //Waits for users action
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; //Users action
import javax.swing.JFrame; //Window
import javax.swing.JButton; //BUTTON!!!
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; //Standard dialogue box

public class ButtonClass extends JButton {

private JButton regular;
private JButton custom;

public ButtonClass() { // Constructor
    super("The title"); // Title
    setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // Default layout

    regular = new JButton("Regular Button");
    add(regular);

    Icon b = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("img.png"));
    Icon x = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("swag.png"));
    custom = new JButton("Custom", b);
    custom.setRolloverIcon(x); //When you roll over the button that says custom the image will change from b to x
    add(custom);

    Handlerclass handler = new Handlerclass();
    regular.addActionListener(handler);
    custom.addActionListener(handler);

}

 private class Handlerclass implements ActionListener { // This class is inside the other  class


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eventvar) { // This will happen
                                                        // when button is
                                                        // clicked
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("%s", eventvar.getActionCommand()));//Opens a new window with the name of the button
    }
}



}
```

I have searched everywhere for this problem and found nothing. Please tell me how to resolve this issue about exiting my window.
Thanks!

Comment: So you want to exit a button?

Comment: No, I wan't to exit the window, which consists of a button.

Comment: Then you have to call `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` on a JFrame

Comment: That is done here right? press.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Comment: Where should I put that part?

Comment: `public class ButtonClass extends JButton` No, it isn't a JFrame.

Comment: If the frame is named myFrame, call `myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`; don't call it on the button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're a little confused as you're creating a class that extends JButton, and calling `setVisible(true)` on it as if it were a top-level window such as a JFrame or JDialog, and that doesn't make sense. Since it isn't a top-level window it also makes sense to not have a default close operation or understand what that means.

I suggest that you call this method only on top-level windows such as on a JFrame or JDialog and the like. As a side recommendation, I usually avoid `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` and instead more often do `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);` which gives it a little more flexibility.

Edit: actually, just change your class to extends JFrame not extends JButton.

Make sure your image path to your resources is correct. For example:

[image]

Comment: @Billybobsteven: actually, just change your class to `extends JFrame` not `extends JButton`.

Comment: Thank you so much Hovercraft Full of Eels, the original error went away, but now I have this error:                                                             Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at Buttons.ButtonClass.<init>(ButtonClass.java:24)
 at Buttons.Main_buttons.main(Main_buttons.java:8)

Comment: Please explain what to do to fix it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I think there may still be a compiler error on that line...? Please help

Comment: @Billybobsteven: This exception is not a compiler error as your code compiles **and** runs. Your images are not being found as you're probably not looking in the right place for them.

Comment: I both the images in my source folder, with all my packages. Is this the right place?

Comment: AMAZING! Thank you so much it worked! After searching the web for days I found the answer! I have marked you best answer and will hit the like button as soon as I get 15 reputation! **I still do have one more question though: my custom button is much larger than my regular button, can I change the size and keep the image (and roll over image) proportionate?** Again, I can't thank you enough for the hard work and time you put into such a scrupulous helpful answer!

Answer (score 1):

that method is defined for `JFrame`, not `JButton`. You're calling it on an instance of a class that extends `JButton`

Comment: So how should I call it then?

Answer (score 0):

The JFrame.Exit_on_close must be used in a JFrame, and you are extending from JButton.

To set a JButton to close a JFrame its something like this.

```
public class MyClass extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private JButton button = new JButton("Button");
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new MyClass();
    }

    public MyClass() {
        setSize(300, 300);
        button.addActionListener(this);


        panel.add(button);
        add(panel);

        setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        this.dispose();
    }


}
```