# How to set the right path to image in java?

Tags: java, image, drawimage

I am trying to load and draw it with paint method in java whatever the way I write the path it always shows an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
```

I have the image at the same folder with the class

This is the line that I am loading image in

```
    Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("pepsi.png"));
```

Comment: Did you check      this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424834/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-input-null-when-using-imageio-read-to-lo)

Comment: Yes and I am still getting the same exception 
I tried every solution written there

Comment: Are you sure the file is in the same place as the java file? could be in another class folder, put it in the same folder as the class **this** code runs.

Comment: Yes they are at the same place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [MKYong's tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/). It shows you where to put your image.
If you want the image to be loaded as "resource", you have to put it in the resources folder. You project structure would be like this:

```
MyProject
    +--src
        +--main
            +--java
            |    +-com
            |       +--me
            |           +--Main.java
            +--resources
                 +--pepsi.jpg
```

and in your `Main` class you execute that snippet:

```
try {
    Image img= ImageIO.read(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("pepsi.jpg"));
    System.out.println(img.getWidth(null));  //this is just a test, when it prints out the width of your image, you have the right file loaded 
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check your output folder... the 'pepsi.png' (maybe case sensitive) must be in same folder as the class file your calling from

Comment: it's at the same folder as I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Try to test it like this.

If the file is by the java file and my class is in a package called

```
net.ilightwas.MyClass
```

it should be like

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("net/ilightwas/pepsi.png"));
```

This will probably help you find the mistake.